# html textbox in ipad

Tags: html, ipad

I have html textbox in my login page that textbox have top shadow in ipad. how can I remove it?

Here's my code:

```
<div style="width:205px; height:30px; float:left; background-color:transparent;">
<input name="UserNameBox" type="text"  id="tbEmail" style="margin-top:2px; outline-     style:none; -webkit-border: 0px none transparent; border:0px none transparent; font-size:1em; height:1.5em; background-color:transparent;" tabindex="1" runat="server" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) validateExample()"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `box-shadow: none;`?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div style="width:205px; height:30px; float:left; background-color:transparent;">
<input name="UserNameBox" type="text"  id="tbEmail" style="margin-top:2px; outline-     style:none; -webkit-border: 0px none transparent; border:0px none transparent; font-size:1em; height:1.5em; background-color:transparent;box-shadow: none !important;" tabindex="1" runat="server" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) validateExample()"/>
```